# Deleting LogCat saved filters in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, logcat, android-logcat

I am using Eclipse and ADT for my Android project. All is mostly fine, however one thing is bugging me.

Sometimes I create filters to LogCat (and sometimes Eclipse creates a "session filter", whatever that is). I have two main filters, one for showing only things for my application and one for my specific tag to see only my app's custom output.

But, these filters are left in the saved filters box. I would like to get them away.

I have tried pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> and right clicking the filters (no context menu). There are no buttons I have thought would help.

The "session filter" was however removed when I restarted Eclipse.

Is there a way to clean up unused filter from the LogCat view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a red '-' sign on the top of the list, next to the green '+' sign you used to add a filter.

Comment: Thanks! My filters list was resized so narrow it wasn't there ^^